# Mesos scheduling - how this works?

Tags: mesos

I am trying to figure out how to use Mesos.
I have running mesos master and slave running (in single-node setup).

And I have understood that framework listens for resource offers and accepts theme if he can, and after that it goes to the executor to execute the task.

How I can send to mesos "Hi, I want to execute some task with 1 cpu and 256 mb", who's task is? the framework? or there is another api for doing this?

Yosi

Comment: which API are you using?  C++, JVM, Python, or Go?

Comment: My question was generic according to all implementations, but I am using JVM (Scala)

Comment: The various APIs are quite similar. For JVM, there's a good example at http://mesosphere.io/2013/08/01/distributed-fault-tolerant-framework-apache-mesos/ https://github.com/guenter/mesos-getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understood it finally after a debugging session :)

The framework gets a resource offer, when it get a resource offer he checks whether he have a task to launch the matches the resource offer - If so, he runs the task.

I thought there was an external service that I need to call and it will initiate a resource offer.

Comment: Mesos is called a "two level" scheduler: the Mesos driver makes resource offers to the registered frameworks, then the frameworks must decide whether or not to consume the offers.